# Can I Change My Location Button in Android Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

We have a my location Icon in google maps like
[image: My Location Icon]
I want to change this icon button with my desired Icon is there any way to replace this icon in the Google Maps. How can i do that in Android.

As the Question was unclear so i am adding Additional information. In https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3093609?hl=en you can see in section **Get directions based on your location** in point number 2 the icon had been shown [image]

The Section just below in **Fix your location-> Understand Location Symbols** also explains these icons.

As you can see it is not the marker it's a location button as i had written **So my question is how can i change that icon (location button) to my desired icon.**

See this icon button is also shown in the google maps icon pic
[image]

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826345/android-maps-api-v2-change-mylocation-icon) may help you changing your icon

Comment: Whoever is Marking it down, if they think it is too easy then please provide the answer then mark it down

Comment: @SonuRaj What you have told is changing the myLocation Icon but i wanna change the shape of the button which is located in the top right side on the map

Comment: This answer has what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883235/google-map-for-android-my-location-custom-button

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can,

I solved this problem in my map fragment by re positioning my location button to the right bottom corner of view using code below, here is my MapsActivity.java :-

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    View mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_map);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapView = mapFragment.getView();
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

        if (mapView != null &&
                mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")) != null) {
            // Get the button view
            View locationButton = ((View) mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
            // and next place it, on bottom right (as Google Maps app)
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                    locationButton.getLayoutParams();
            // position on right bottom
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);
        }

    }
}
```

And here is layout of fragment :-

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.infogird.www.location_button_reposition.MapFragment">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

I hope, this will solve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Does it works with signed apk? Its working for me in debug mode but not in release mode.

Comment: what is the exact problem you are facing in release mode ? I think, in the map API V2, the ONLY thing that change between a release version and a debug version is the Key that you register here code.google.com/apis/console If debug is working and final release is not, it's the only change necessary. So I suggest you to double check the hash code of your release keystore and make sure that it's properly input on the Google API Console. @seema

Comment: its done. Issue was, we had used integer value 1. Replaced it with Integer.parseInt("1") and it worked.

Comment: I am glad, you did it. But the code given above itself uses Integer.parseInt("1"); @seema

Answer (score 2):

Something I am using

```
    ImageView btnMyLocation = (ImageView) ((View) mapFragment.getView().findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
    btnMyLocation.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_current_location);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
            btnMyLocation.getLayoutParams();

    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);
    btnMyLocation.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Hope it will help...

Comment: Why are you hardcoding then parsing integer values? Beyond that you should try to explain what the code is doing to help the OP understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an late reply but this code works for me ..

```
     ImageView btnMyLocation = (ImageView) ((View) mapFragment.getView().findViewById(1).getParent()).findViewById(2);
        btnMyLocation.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_location_circle);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                btnMyLocation.getLayoutParams();
        // position on right bottom
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);
```

Happy coding..!