# Changing the drawable/src of the setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true)

Tags: android, maps, android-drawable

As the title says I would like to programmatically change the icon of the crosshair in the setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true) button. If this is not possible, I would like to know how to tint the icon if possible. If it's unclear which button I'm talking about here is a photo. [image: top right button]

Edit 1: While the link provided by Zainal Fahrudin does address how to move the button, I am still unable to tint the icon itself without tinting the whole button or replace the icon. Below is what I have now. You can see the black icon on top of the blue icon in the background. [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I Change My Location Button in Android Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27794221/can-i-change-my-location-button-in-android-maps)

Comment: It is not possible to just tint the icon. You should rather replace the icon with yours