# Change Default Buttons in Google Map Api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Currently I'm working with **Google-Map-Api 2** And I want to change Button Style of Location in top-right-corner of the Map. is it possible ?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883235/google-map-for-android-my-location-custom-button