# android Google Maps change MyLocation icon to Material icon

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using Google Maps API in my android app and I want to change the appearance of my location button from the old one with square to the new round material design icon.

Current one:
[image: old]

I wanna change it to this one:

[image: new]

Also, how do I change its position from upper right corner to bottom right corner?

Below is my code for XML file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.bhoiwala.locationmocker.MapsActivity" >
  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Below is the code on how I'm using it:

```
 private void updateLocationUI() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    }
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883235/google-map-for-android-my-location-custom-button

Comment: When you will run code on API >21 then it will show material design mylocation icon

Answer (score 1):

you can change to

```
 mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
```

Create your own icon and change the location on click event

Comment: I'd like to point out that you can simply disable the button in UI after calling mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false); so then: mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false); This effectively hides the button while still allowing you to start/stop location updates in your own fab onclick

Answer (score 0):

Add marker in your latLng points of  map.Paste the custom image in drawable folder 
then call like this

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position( latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.customicon)));
```