# binding.mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent() NullPointerException

Tags: android, google-maps

This question about Google Maps and customization my location button. I hide native my location button and add my own my location button. But in some of the phones I see crash in Crashlytics.

**Sample code:**

```
View parent = (View) (binding.mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent());
        android.widget.ImageView locationButton = parent.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
        locationButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        locationButton.callOnClick();
```

**Crash log:**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewParent android.view.View.getParent()' on a null object reference
       at com.example.ui.main.settings.map.MapController.clickMyLocationButton(MapController.java:269)
       at com.example.ui.main.settings.map.MapController.onCurrentLocationRequested(MapController.java:236)
       at com.example.ui.main.settings.map.MapViewModel.onFindClick(MapViewModel.java:205)
       at com.example.databinding.ControllerMapsBindingImpl._internalCallbackOnClick(ControllerMapsBindingImpl.java:387)
       at com.example.generated.callback.OnClickListener.onClick(OnClickListener.java:11)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5106)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20329)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: Seems that your map object is not loaded yet and you called get parent method on it. Use this only in onMapReady function. Also place try catch statement to avoid crash on exception.